# Factory reset an LG P500h

Tags: factory-reset, lg-optimus-one

I just managed to prevent my LG P500h android phone from booting by uninstalling the home screen. I'm not a very smart man.

Now, my phone can only get to the android logo, and is totally unusable.

How do I reset the phone back to the way it was before? I've tried going into recovery mode, but I don't know how to select any of the options. All the guides that I've found said to use the "camera button", but my device doesn't have one!

Help is much appreciated at this point.

Answer (score 2):

[This site](http://mobilemeerut.boardforum.ca/t9-lg-p500-hard-reset-solution-here) and [this other](http://mistermobiless.blogspot.com/2010/12/lg-optimus-one-p500-hard-reset.html) confirm this method:

1. Power off device completely
2. Hold down the `Home` and `Volume Down` buttons
3. Press and hold the `Power` button until the device powers on
4. Follow the on-screen instructions to reset your device

Comment: I tried that, but after the "reset", I still don't have a home screen.

Comment: but it gets past the boot screen?

Comment: Yes.         whitespace filler

Comment: I would try installing something like [ADW Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adw.launcher&hl=en) via the Play Store or adb (if you can get an .apk). That could get you a working launcher for now. I would try to find a stock ROM for your phone and extract the .apk for your phone, if you would like the stock launcher back.

Comment: I can't get into the play store. All interaction with my phone has to be done through the recovery screen and over USB.

Comment: install it online, via [play.google.com](http://play.google.com), after you sign in with your Gmail. If you want to do it via USB, I'd suggest finding an `.apk` file for another launcher and installing it via ADB.

Comment: The phone is no longer jailbroken. I just "reset" it, but all it did was restore what it could - which didn't include the home screen because I uninstalled that like a damned fool.